# How can I link a C websocket server running on AWS Linux with the client on a virtual machine locally?

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, sockets, ubuntu, amazon-ec2

I recently wrote an echoserver / echoclient program in C for the online class I'm taking (Graduate Introduction to Operating Systems, [here](https://classroom.udacity.com/courses/ud923)). I was able to complete it with the help of (and modification from Beej's Network guide ([here](https://beej.us/guide/bgnet/html/#client-server-background)). I can run it just fine on my Ubuntu 20.04 virtual machine, running on my Windows 10 laptop. However, I'm trying to run the echoserver on an AWS Linux instance and the echoclient from the Ubuntu VM, as my end goal is building a client program that has a central server data repository. However, I'm running into issues where I start the echoserver C code on the AWS EC2 instance through SSH-ing by PuTTy, then I run the echoclient on the Ubuntu VM, but it can't connect (the error I receive on the client side is that it failed the `connect` phase of the socket call). I've tried the following steps:

- Editing the inbound rules of the security configuration of the EC2 instance to allow for 'All TCP' connections from the IP address that comes up when I run `curl ifconfig.me` on my Ubuntu machine
- Changing the network setting of my Ubuntu VM from NAT to Bridged Network
- Testing port access by `telnet <AWS Public IP> <PortNo>` - which led to "Connection Refused" error
- Ensuring that my outgoing ports aren't blocked by following [these](https://superuser.com/questions/1336054/how-to-detect-if-a-network-is-blocking-outgoing-ports) instructions

I've looked through the AWS pages ([here](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ec2-windows-unable-connect-port/)) as well as multiple developer / SO threads (best one I found so far [here](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=146748)) and I just can't seem to figure out out. If anyone could help me out, I'd really appreciate it. I'm happy to post my server & client code if that would be of help.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out: was missing the following line of code in my server.

`hints.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE;`